# Linq To Sql Sub Query Complex

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

### tblItem

- Name
- ProductID

### tblProduct

- Name
- ProductID
- CategoryID

### tblCategory

- Name
- CategoryID

  ```
  var itms = from item in CMP.tblItems
      let t2s = (from  g in CMP.tblProducts
      where g.CategoryID==CatID
      select g.ProductID)
      where item.Name.Contains(Model) && item.ProductID.ToString() == t2s.ToString()
      select new { item.Name };
  ```

My problem is more than one product is return to t2s (Sub-Query). if i add FirstOrDefault() to Sub-Query then it will match it with only one product id! i need to match will all productid(s) it returns.

Comment: What result you want to get? If you need to check if item.ProductID is in t2s you could try using `Contains` e.g. `t2s.Contains(item.ProductID)`. You also might consider using `Join` instead of subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One:

```
var itms=from item in CMP.tblItems
         from g in CMP.tblProducts
         where item.Name.Contains(Model) && item.ProductID == g.ProductID && g.CategoryID == CatID
         select new {item.Name};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the navigation properties that LINQ-to-SQL creates for you. `Item` should have property `Product`. So you can simply do this:

```
var itms = from item in CMP.tblItems
    where item.Name.Contains(Model) && item.Product.CategoryID = CatId
    select new { item.Name };
```